# How to use Solr search that is included with Nutch-1.2?

Tags: solr, nutch

There's some good (outdated though) tutorials on how to integrate Nutch with Solr to get a full web search experience. In the latest Nutch release (1.2), Solr is integrated out-of-the-box in the Nutch distribution. Question is: How to use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the nutch solr schema from NUTCH_HOME/conf/schema.xml to SOLR_HOME/solr/conf/
Then you can use the nutch solr index command to update the solr index from nutch.
It is better explained here: http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/03/09/nutch-solr/